# How to download a file using FileResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I have a list in my view with an ActionLink button 'Download' and I want them to download a file when they click the link. The file is located in a map in my project.

**View:**

```
<div id="right-column-links">
    <h2>Your active links</h2>
    @if (lstLinks.Count == 0)
    {
        <p>You have no active links yet.</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in lstLinks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Url)</td> 
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Put inactive", "LinkInActive", new { linkid=item.LinkId }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want this link inactive?');" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download Qrcode", "DownloadQrcode", new { linkid=item.LinkId })</td> 
                </tr> 
            }
        </table>       
    }
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult DownloadQrcode(int linkid)
{
    Qrcode Qrcode = DbO.getQrcodebyLinkId(linkid);
    string image = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Qrcodes\\" + Qrcode.Image;
    string contentType = "image/jpg";

    return File(image, contentType, "Qrcode-" + Qrcode.QrcodeId);
}
```

The linkid comes from the selected link in the list. Then I lookup what qrcode matches the linkid in my database. From this qrcode object I get the image name. Example (qrcode-1337). Then I'am not sure what to do. I lookup the path where my project is stored and attach the map Qrcodes to it (where all the images are stored) and the image name. This returns me a link that he doesn't find.

**Map location:**

C:\Users\stage\Desktop\Immo-QR\Immo-QR\Immo-QR\Qrcodes

This doesn't seem to work. I am not sure how I should use FileResult. Can anyone explain this? Or show me another way?

**EDIT:**

A user suggested me to put the images in the App_Data file which I did under a map Qrcodes.

To save the file I use this code:

string path = Server.MapPath("~");

```
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + "\\App_Data\\Qrcodes\\qrcode-" + qrcodeid + ".jpg", bytes);
```

If I use "~\App_Data\Qrcodes\qrcode-" instead of the above, It doesn't work either.

I still get this error: Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.

**SOLUTION:**

With this code it works!

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadQrcode(int linkid)
{
    Qrcode Qrcode = DbO.getQrcodebyLinkId(linkid);
    string path = Server.MapPath("~");
    Stream image = new FileStream(path + "\\App_Data\\Qrcodes\\" + Qrcode.Image + ".jpg", FileMode.Open);

    return File(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `string image` line to `Stream image`.

This will help understand if you can't read the file. Your `return File` line will take a Stream with no issues.

Comment: How do I use the Stream object? I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: `Stream image = = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)`

Comment: I get the same error. So this means he doesn't find the file?

Comment: @NanouPonette Put a breakpoint on `Stream image = ...` and run in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

I think the path to the file is incorrect.

If you use `~\\Qrcodes\\filename` it will translate to `<appRootDirectory>\\QrCodes\\filename`.

Also remember that IIS runs as a separate user in most cases, which does not have a home directory like a regular user.

I would suggest you move the Qrcodes to AppData folder or AppGlobalResources folder.

If you dont want to do that, you need to provide absolute path to Qrcodes folder.

Comment: I did what you told me too but unfortunately without succes. Updated my question!