# How to download files to client machine in C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filesystems, streaming, document

I have a method that converts files and downloads them as expected when on localhost. However when this application is deployed I see that the files are downloading to a location on the server instead of the clients machine. What is the correct way to actually download the files to a location on the clients machine instead of on the server when deployed.

```
public async Task<string> studentAnswersBulkDownloadString(int testId, int[] studentIds)
{
    var folder = KnownFolderFinder.GetFolderFromKnownFolderGUID(new Guid("374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B"));
    string tempFolderName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    testEntity = await GetAsync(testId);
    root = folder + @"\" + testEntity.TestName.PadRight(5);
    string subdir = root + tempFolderName;

    if (!Directory.Exists(root))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(subdir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(subdir);
    }
    
    foreach (var studentId in studentIds)
    {
        if (testId > 0)
        {
            // var testEntity = await GetAsync(testId);
            var test = await GetUserAnswerDocAsync(testId, studentId);
            //var testEntity = await GetAsync(testId);
                        
            var testGradeEntity = await GetTestGradeEntityAsync(testEntity.SectorId ?? 0); 

            if (test is null) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
    
            Syncfusion.Compression.Zip.ZipArchive zipArchive = new Syncfusion.Compression.Zip.ZipArchive();
            zipArchive.DefaultCompressionLevel = Syncfusion.Compression.CompressionLevel.Best;
                     
            string path = root;
            string fileName = "test";
    
            var answerFileToDownLoad = await GetUserAnswerFileDownload(testId, studentId);
            var fileNameDetails = await GetStudentFileNameDetails(testId, studentId);
            var appendNo = GenerateRandomNo(); 
            var blob = test.TestDocument;

            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(subdir + "/" + testEntity.TestName.PadRight(5) + "-" + fileNameDetails.ExamNo.PadRight(5) + "-"+ fileNameDetails.Name + "-"+ fileNameDetails.Surname +"-"+ appendNo+ ".docx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                stream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(subdir);

                ZipArchiveItem item = new ZipArchiveItem(zipArchive, "SampleFile.cs", stream, true, (Syncfusion.Compression.FileAttributes)attributes);
                zipArchive.AddItem(item);
            }

            //ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(subdir, "destination.zip", CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);
            startPath = subdir;
            zipFolderName = "ExportedAnswers.zip".PadLeft(5);
            zipPath = startPath + zipFolderName;
        }
        else
        {
            return @"C:\AnswersExport" + "BulkAnswerDownload.zip";
        }
    }

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(root);
    var dirGuid = new DirectoryInfo(subdir); 

    dir.Delete(true);
    dirGuid.Delete(true);

    return zipPath;
}
```

Comment: Well,  first you need to understand that there is a difference between "write to disc locally" and "download" and what that difference is. Then you may investigate CDNs (content delivery network) and/or blob storage if we are talking "cloud".

Comment: A 'server' (your code) cannot directly communicate with the O/S on the client machine, to find out 'special' folders (KnownFolderFinder in your case).  That is what a browser is for - it reads files from the server, and potentially, saves them to the folder that the user/browser has designated.  The server can only suggest where to put the file on the client, and even then, it's probably only the filename/extension that will be used by the client.

Comment: You have to return file result as this issue if you try with .net core:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275077/how-to-download-a-file-using-fileresult